# ModuleNotFound: How can I import objects from other folder in the same project?

Tags: python, visual-studio, import, modulenotfounderror

I have the following project structure and I would like to import the function "get()", which is inside the main.py from the Folder_A, into the model.py file from Folder_BA.

```
Project
     |_____ Folder_A
     |          |_____ main.py
     |          |_____ model.py
     |          |_____ constants.py
     |          |_____ functions.py
     |
     |_____ Folder_B
                |_____ Folder_BA
                |         |_____ main.py
                |         |_____ model.py
                |         |_____ functions.py
                |
                |_____ Folder_BB
                          |_____ main.py
                          |_____ model.py
                          |_____ functions.py
```

I tried coding inside the model.py file from Folder BA the following code but it didnt work:

```
from Folder_A.main import get

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Folder_A'
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4383597/6797569):

> By default, you can't. When importing a file, Python only searches the directory that the entry-point script is running from and sys.path which includes locations such as the package installation directory (it's actually a little more complex than this, but this covers most cases).

So a few things you can do:

1. Try structuring your files into packages, adding a `__init__.py` empty file inside the folder so it can be imported to other files.
2. You can add a new path using `sys` and then just use regular import

```
sys.path.append('/path/to/Project/Folder_A')
from main import get
```